# Can this definite integral of an inverse Laplace transform by simplified?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

Can either of the below expressions involving an unknown analytic function $h(s,t)$ and the inverse Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ be simplified?
$$
\int\limits_{0}^1 \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{h(s,t)}{s} \right\} \mathrm{d}t;
$$

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{h(s,t)}{s} \right\} \mathrm{d}t.
$$

Comment: Fix $t$. Then the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{h(s,t)}{s}$ is $\int_{0}^{x}(L^{-1}h)(x-\tau ,t))d\tau $, so you can express it as a double integral over a translate of the inverse transform of $h$.

Comment: Does it even make sense to speak of "inverting" some function of $t$?

Comment: This is coming a bit out of context: $h$ is really a function of a generating series $f$ and a formal variable $x$. $\int \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{h(s,t)}{s} \right\} \mathrm{d}t$ is a linear transformation on the generating series. So $s$ and $t$ don't represent any actual quantities and the inversion makes sense at least symbolically. Essentially it's a gadget to turn negative powers (of $s$) into reciprocals factorials. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it as although it works for my purpose in theory, in practice the inverse Laplace is only doable in too limited cases.